# Is it possible to see all the players who have won a particular medal?

Tags: illyriad

Does Illyriad offer (or is it possible to find out from another site) a way to see all the players who have won a particular medal?  For example, any of the thousands of players who won the 5th anniversary medal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you can award it. The Award Medal page shows who it was designed by and who it has been awarded to.

http://elgea.illyriad.co.uk/#/Prestige/MedallistAward